# Why won't my buffered `String` match with the `RegEx` pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I've created a bluetooth data listener that stores incoming data into a `String` then checks whether it matches a regular expression pattern then resets the `String`. This is done because the data does not arrive whole in one instance so that I can manipulate with it when I get the full text. For example when I send `"Hello Android!"` to my device via bluetooth with my method and print the data, it would be printed like this:

`#1 New data! "H"`

`#2 New data! "ello Android!`

As you can see, the whole string cannot be sent at one instance which means that two strings get sent instead and I'm sure that most people know about that. That is why I am using `RegEx` to help me with that.

Instead, I am sending a randomly generated number between two different characters then try to parse them. For example `"<128>"`. Now, I want to get the whole number so that I can use it, like parse it to an int or something like that. But only when my `String` buffer gets the whole data that is being sent which is determined by a `RegEx` pattern that goes like `([<])(-?\d+)([>])`. `character`<`followed by any positive/negative number followed by character '>'`.

The problem is that it does not match the pattern at all for unknown reasons.

```
String szBuffer = "";

if(mmInputStream.available() > 0) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] bData = new byte[1024];

    while(mmInputStream.available() > 0) {
        int read = mmInputStream.read(bData);
        builder.append(new String(bData, 0, read, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    szBuffer += builder.toString();

    Log.d("SZ_BUFFER", szBuffer); // For this example, "<128>" gets sent into pieces.

    // <n>
    if(Pattern.matches("([<])(-?\\d+)([>])", szBuffer)) {
        Log.d("SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH", "MATCH!");
        szBuffer = ""; // Reset the buffer for new data
    }
    else
        Log.d("SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH", "NO MATCH...");
}
```

Here's a live output:

```
D/SZ_BUFFER: <
D/SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH: NO MATCH...
D/SZ_BUFFER: <128>
D/SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH: NO MATCH...
```

As you can see, it gets sent into two pieces, but when it gets the whole text together it should be a match, but isn't. Why? If I replace `szBuffer` with a constant `String` like this:

```
if(Pattern.matches("([<])(-?\\d+)([>])", "<128>"))
```

It's a match, meaning that the pattern should be correct, but when it checks for `szBuffer` it is never a match.

Comment: Maybe invisible characters? Check the length of szBuffer.

Comment: It really seems like you should be doing your processing on `byte`s (perhaps with a `ByteBuffer`) and then only converting to `String` at the end.

Comment: Just a note, not an answer; you don't need to use `[ ]` unless you want to match on multiple characters. Also don't use groups `( )` if you don't need to reference or unpack them. try `<(-?\d+)>`

Comment: I have updated the part of my code where I convert the bytes to string. The length, however, is wrong and it seems as if there are invisible characters!

Comment: @mayamar, why does that happen?

Comment: @wEight: I don't know. It was just a logical conclusion. Try to find out what invisible characters there are. Maybe that's helping. I think it could be chars with code zero. That would mean that the source uses zero-terminated strings like C. But that's just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the data contains invisible characters which was confirmed by getting the data's length being wrong. The solution is to check every character then store them only if they match a certain criteria like this regular expression method:

```
for(char c : builder.toString().toCharArray()) {
    String s = String.valueOf(c);

    if(Pattern.matches("<|>|-|-?\\d+", s)){
        szBuffer += s;
    }
}
```

This is not the best nor cleanest solution, but it does solve my problem. I am still learning Regular Expressions and the many many combinations in algorithms. All new recommendations are welcome and will be added below this one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, [`Pattern.matches(regex,string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher-java.lang.CharSequence-) is equivalent to `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).matches()`, which is equivalent to `string.matches(regex)`. This means that you are checking if the *entire string* matches the regex. If you want to check if the string *contains* your end-of-string marker, you can use `Matcher.find` instead:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([<])(-?\\d+)([>])");

String szBuffer = "";

if(mmInputStream.available() > 0) {
    ...

    szBuffer += convertedBytes;

    Log.d("SZ_BUFFER", szBuffer); 

    // <n>
    if(pattern.matcher(szBuffer).find()) {
        Log.d("SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH", "MATCH!");
        szBuffer = "";
    }
    else
        Log.d("SZ_BUFFER_ISMATCH", "NO MATCH...");
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to check the whole string, also, I am getting invisible characters because the `szBuffer`'s length is longer than the amount of characters in it.

Comment: I've found a simple solution I will post right away. But +1 for that since it could still be useful for me in the future and for others too.